# Tradingview Pinescript Strategy Exit on EMA cross doesn't work

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create a strategy with an exit at the intersection of the EMA10 and EMA25, but for some reason it makes entries correctly but doesn't exit when the EMAs cross.

```
if (conditionEntryLong)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (conditionEntryShort)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)

conditionExitLong=crossover(ema(close, 10), ema(close, 25))
conditionExitShort=crossover(ema(close, 25), ema(close, 10))
if (conditionExitLong)
    strategy.exit("exitLong",  from_entry="Long")

if (conditionExitShort)
    strategy.exit("exitShort",  from_entry="short")
```

Answer (score 0):

`strategy.exit` is used when you want to exit based on some price (take profit or stop loss).

You want to close your position conditionally. Therefore, you should use `strategy.close()`.

## Edit:

`strategy.close("exitLong")` will look for an entry id `exitLong` which does not exist. You need to use the same entry id in your `strategy.close()` calls.

```
if (conditionExitLong)
    strategy.close("Long")
if (conditionExitShort)
    strategy.close("Short")
```

Comment: I tried with strategy.close but it's the same thing, it doesn't exit when the EMAs cross, but it exit only when there is a reversal entry:

if (conditionEntryLong)
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)
if (conditionEntryShort)
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
conditionExitLong=crossover(ema(close, 10), ema(close, 25))
conditionExitShort=crossunder(ema(close, 25), ema(close, 10))
if (conditionExitLong)
    strategy.close("exitLong")
if (conditionExitShort)
    strategy.close("exitShort")

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: See my edit please.